# Adding a number to individual values in a dataframe column based on length of value, R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say that I have a dataframe with a column that has values that are either three or four numbers in length. What I want to do, is that whenever length = 3, I want to insert a 0 (zero) at the start of the number, for all values in the column, like this:

```
320 -> 0320
0672 -> 0672
120 -> 0120
```

Is there any way to do this? I thought of some kind of for-loop for this, but that may be unnecessarily complicated... (I am quite new to programming in general).

```
for ( i in dataset$col_name){
 if (nchar(dataset$col_name == 3)){
  dataset$col_name <- 0 + dataset$col_name
 } else {
  dataset$col_name <- dataset$col_name
 }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have u tried `sprintf` i.e. `sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(c(320, "0672", 120)))` or use `library(stringr);str_pad(c("320", "0672", "120"), 4, pad = 0)`

Comment: Does this also work on a dataframe where i do not know the values that I want to change, only the length? (The dataframe contains over 4000 entries of various 3 and 4 length numbers)

Comment: Yes, it would work.  i.e. `sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(dataset$col_name))`

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly